# Toast is repeatedly getting printed repeatedly

Tags: android-context, android-livedata, android-toast, mutablelivedata

After performing some firebase operations, I'm trying to set different values for `MutableLiveData<String>` according to the text typed in a text box.  (value is fetched from firebase for validating the data typed in the text box)

I'm trying to display the `String` as a toast using `it.toast(context)` while observing the `LiveData` from the fragment (when a button is pressed).

Whenever the text is changed (clearing the first text and typing the second one) and when the button is pressed, the previous toast shows up (the one for the first text) and after some time, the respective toast shows up. navigating to the previous fragment somehow solves this problem but I don't want to do that. Also, toast is displayed multiple times.

The code which I use in the fragment part:

```
ViewModel.getText(Text.toString(),args.Name) //responsible for setting the LiveData

ViewModel.messageLiveData.observe(this@Fragment, Observer {
                        it.toast(context)    //trying to display the live data
                        textBox.setText("")
                        //  findNavController().navigateUp()
                    })
```

Comment: Your function name is getText but you're using it to set the LiveData. Can you please explain why is it so?

Comment: Is the question title a pun on the repeated situation? ;-)

Comment: nice one. Didn't see that. Hopefully, no one edits it

Answer (score 0):

I used two `MutableLiveData<String>` variables and observed both of them individually, so they were being displayed only when each of the variable was notified. But would love to know other alternatives where I can use just one `LiveData` variable.